# How to know total hard disk space being used?

Tags: disk

Including all partitions. Without manually adding.

Comment: Does this help you, in terminal type: df -h

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you want. `df` would for my box (and it's 160gb disk) include ~24TB of data using `df` as it'll include network shares I've mounted; do you want those? or local drives?  only mounted? etc.  It's unclear as I read your question.

Comment: @guiverc I want to buy a new laptop. For deciding hard disk capacity i should buy, i want to know how much space i'm already using on my current hard disk, e.g. 300GB out of total 500GB capacity. I want total of used space in all the local partitions, mounted or non-mounted.

Comment: I don't believe it's possible to view unmounted disk/partition usage. The OS needs to mount the disk/partition to be able to see and report that information.

Comment: @Broadsworde GParted shows usage of my unmounted ntfs partition.

Comment: So I see. Good to know. But does it give you a total, without adding?

Answer (score 3):

From the [Ubuntu man page for df](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/df.1.html), try the --total option to see a grand total. Combine with -h for more readable output.

```
df -h --total
```

Comment: `df --total` doesn't include non-mounted partitions.

Comment: This is the expected result. Are you not able to mount the partitions before running the command?

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Broadsworde's comment. The easiest way is to open a terminal and type in `df -h`.

You can also install a graphical disk manager such as `gnome-disks`and use that instead if you hate using the terminal. But `df -h` is still faster and easier, plus it's already there, you don't have to install anything.